# RESTful API for HTTP DELETE doesnt check for null

Tags: javascript, rest, express, mongoose, http-delete

Im currently writing a RESTful API for a webservice but im having trouble. Im trying to **delete** an mail, but first i want to check if the mail even **exists**. My problem is that it doesn't check if mail is null and doesn't respond with a **404**. Im working with **express** and **mongoose**

```js
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    Mail.findById(id)
      .exec()
      .then((mail) => {
        if (!mail) {
          console.log(mail) // returns null
          return res.status(404);
        }
      })
      .then(
        Mail.deleteOne({ _id: id })
          .exec()
          .then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: 'Mail deleted',
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
          })
      );
  });
```

Comment: Can you add to your question information about what is the expected vs actual behavior?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want if the mail is null to respond with an HTTP status code of 404. Otherwise it should continue by deleting the found mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do the the deletion part of the code inside the first then block as an else statement. You are not returning anything that the next then block can use.

you could do:

```
Mail.findById(id)
      .exec()
      .then((mail) => {
        if (!mail) {
          console.log(mail) // returns null
          return res.status(404).send() //need to send response;
        }
        Mail.deleteOne({ _id: id })
          .exec()
          .then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: 'Mail deleted',
            });
          })
      }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      })
```

PRO TIP: if you don't know it, learn async await. Code will look much cleaner!

Then it would look like this:

```
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
      const mail = await Mail.findById(id);
      if(!mail) {
         return res.status(404).send();
      }

      await Mail.deleteOne({_id: id});      
      res.status(200).json({
              message: 'Mail deleted',
            });
    } catch(e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it looks much cleaner when using async/await. I will look into it. It also works with the code you gave me

Comment: Great, happy to help :)!